# Putting tile layers on top of FusionTable layers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Right now I'm designing a map for a small campus in Google Maps API v3.

I want my map to display layers in the following order (from bottom to top):

```
0 [Google Maps layer (all labels turned off)]
1 [buildings, parking lots, detailed streets and paths] 
2 [additional details (trees)]
3 [highlighted parking lots (toggled on/off)]
4 [highlighted buildings (toggled on/off)]
5 [transparent (street-)labels from google maps]
6 [transparent custom (building-)labels]
7 [markers]
8 [info windows]
```

I got quite far already, but I 'm stuck here:
Layers 1, 2, 5 and 6 are `new google.maps.ImageMapType` layers with tiles, added like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, myMapLayer);
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, myTreeLayer);
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(1, googleLabelLayer);
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(1, myLabelLayer);  
    map.setOptions({styles: stylesArray});
```

Layers 3 and 4 are FusionTables layers with polygons, added like this:

```
parkingLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(#######);
buildingLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(#######);
```

and toogled by a checkbox:

```
function toggleLayer(layer) {
  if(layer.getMap() == null) {
    layer.setMap(map);
  } else {
    layer.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

But the FusionTables layers (3 & 4) are always above my Label Layers (5 & 6), when they should be underneath.
FusionTables layers highlight buildings in color to be better visible, while the labels tell the buildings name. If the FusionTables layer is toggled on, the polygons cover the labels, so the name of the building disappears. Setting the opacity to 50% works for now, but isn't optimal.

I also found out, `OverlayView` has the right position (on top of the map, on top of fusiontables layer, under the markers and infowindows). But I could only use a static image, haven't found a possibility to make tiles work here.

So my question is:
Is there a way to put tiled layers over FusionTables layers?